# OpenCL support on Joule running Ubuntu joule spin?

Tags: opencl

Are there any plans to support OpenCL on the joule?  It has a reasonably powerful GPU which at the moment lies wasted.
OpenCL requires support in the kernel, which is controlled by Ubuntu at the moment and has not released sources so we can patch or include other support in.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I would highly recommend you read our [tour] to get an idea as to how this site works, and how to leverage it effectively. Otherwise, I think this question is more about the Intel Joule than Ubuntu, and as such is off-topic here. We don't know what (if anything) Intel is planning

Comment: Sorry I could have explained this better.  Ubuntu has a joule specific spin: https://developer.ubuntu.com/core/get-started/intel-joule, and the opencl support needs to be in the kernel which appears to be a closed effort between ubuntu and intel, at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell Ubuntu already supports OpenCL on the Intel Joule through the “Intel® SDK for OpenCL* Applications”. ([source](https://gist.github.com/rmcgibbo/6314452) with outdated installation instructions)

Comment: So it looks like the SDK is just an SDK, you still need the underlying ICD (Installable Client Driver) for the hardware platform to provide OpenCL access the CPU and GPU.  Intel does provide OpenCL ICD but it's in the form of kernel patches and only for kernel 4.4, so you have to go through the process of patching, compiling and installing a new kernel.  And Ubuntu haven't released their kernel sources for the joule kernel (and have deleted my responses asking where it is).

Comment: I have had some success with Beignet.  The version of beignet that comes with ubuntu joule (16.04) is ancient - 1.1.1 - and doesn't support the joule cpu/gpu at all.  However, compiling the most recent version (1.3.3) from source: https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/Beignet/ does recognise the GPU and installs a working version of OpenCL ICD.  Which is good progress.